# Validate Azure AD token in a .NET 4.7 API without messing actual validation

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, .net-4.7.2

I have an REST API using JWT tokens to authenticate requests. For one process I need to authenticate the user with Azure AD and get a token. How can I validate that token, send in a request from the user interface, without affecting the already existing authentication flow?

I already did research on the internet and most codes are for .Net Core, or affect the auth flow. I tried with this example
[https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-validate-azure-ad-token-using-console-application/#:~:text=Go%20to%20Developer%20Tools%20%2D%3E%20Network,navigation%2C%20click%20Certificates%20%26%20Secrets](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-validate-azure-ad-token-using-console-application/#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20Developer%20Tools%20%2D%3E%20Network,navigation%2C%20click%20Certificates%20%26%20Secrets).
But nothing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: maybe you can find a sample here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below steps to Validate Azure AD in .NET API

Thanks @Tiny Wang for the comment

- In `Azure Portal` => `Active Directory` => `App Registrations` => click on `New Registration`.
  [image]

[image]

- In Overview page of the newly registered Application, we can find the Client ID, TenantID, which are required later (need to copy those in `web.config` file.

[image]

- Go to `Quickstart` => `WebApplication`  => `ASP.NET` => click on  `Manage this change for me`.

[image]

**Redirect URI** will be added in the newly created App registration by default.
[image]

- Click on `Download the code sample`.
  [image]
- You can see the next steps to proceed with the downloaded Application.
- The project is ready with the app's configuration values.
- Open the project in Visual Studio. Restore the NuGet Packages.

[image]

***My Web.config file***

```cs
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />

    <add key="ClientId" value="ClientID from Newly Registered App" />
    <add key="Tenant" value="******" />
    <add key="Authority" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0" />
    <add key="redirectUri" value="https://localhost:portno/" />
  </appSettings>
```

- Check the configuration values properly, build and run the Application.

***Output***
[image]

[image]

[image]