# Integrating Azure AD Authentication into Legacy ASP.NET Framework 4 Web Project (ASPX) - Need Implementation Guidance

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, authentication, .aspxauth

I'm looking for guidance on integrating Azure AD authentication into a legacy ASP.NET webforms project built for .NET Framework 4 (specifically, `.ASPX` pages). Despite extensive research, I haven't come across any relevant documentation or examples, as most resources seem to focus on newer technologies like ASP.NET MVC and SPAs.

I've successfully registered an application in Azure AD, but I'm struggling with the implementation of the authentication flow. Can someone provide step-by-step instructions or point me to documentation that covers this specific scenario?

My files looks like this:

[image]

[image]

The following code is sample code from `Login.aspx.cs`:

```
protected void SignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string username = txtUsername.Text;
        string password = txtPassword.Text;
        string btnText = btnSignIn.Text;

        // Encrypt the password
        string EncPass = EncryptPassword(password);

        if ("Recover".Equals(btnText))
        {
            password = "blank";
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            // Retrieve user data
            System.Data.DataTable user = GetUserByUsername(username);

            if (user.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if ("Recover".Equals(btnText))
                {
                    // Generate a new password
                    string newPassword = GenerateNewPassword();
                    string saltValueN = GetSaltValue(newPassword);
                    string encPassN = EncryptPassword(newPassword);

                    // Reset the user's password
                    int userId = ResetUserPassword(username, encPassN);

                    if (userId > 0)
                    {
                        // Send the new password via email
                        bool sent = SendEmail(username, newPassword);

                        if (sent)
                        {
                            // Session cleanup and notification
                            Session.RemoveAll();
                            Session.Abandon();
                            ShowMessage("A temporary password has been sent.");
                            UpdateUserStatus(userId, 3); // 2 is verified
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ShowMessage("There was an issue sending your password.");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ShowMessage("There was an issue generating a temporary password.");
                    }

                    ResetFormFields();
                }
                else
                {
                    // Get stored password and validate
                    string storedPassword = GetUserStoredPassword(user);
                    bool validated = ValidatePassword(password, storedPassword);
                    int saltLength = GetSaltLength();
                    string saltValue = GetSaltValue(storedPassword);
                    string hashedPassword = EncryptPasswordWithSalt(password, saltValue);
                    int userID = ValidateUser(username, hashedPassword);

                    if (!btnText.Contains("Change") && userID > 0 && validated)
                    {
                        // Session management and redirection
                        ManageSession(username);
                        RedirectAuthenticatedUser();
                    }
                    else if (btnText.Contains("Change") && userID > 0 && validated)
                    {
                        // Handle password change
                        HandlePasswordChange(user);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Authentication failure handling
                        HandleAuthenticationFailure(userID, validated);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ShowMessage("User not found.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ShowMessage("Username and password are required.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HandleException(ex);
    }
}
```

And the following is sample code from `LoginAs.aspx.cs`:

```
public partial class LoginAs : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsRolePermitted())
        {
            RedirectUnauthorizedAccess();
        }
        
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ConfigurePageLayout();
        }
    }

    protected void SignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = txtUsername.Text;
        
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
        {
            int userID = AuthenticateUser(username, "Test");
            
            if (userID == -1)
            {
                InitiateUserSession(username);
                RedirectAuthenticatedUser();
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayAuthenticationError();
            }
        }
    }

    private bool IsRolePermitted()
    {
        // Check user's role permission
        return RoleItem.IsRoleItemPermittedToUser(UserName.GetUserLogin(), 31);
    }

    private void RedirectUnauthorizedAccess()
    {
        // Redirect to an unauthorized access page
        Response.Redirect("~/UnAuthorizedAccess.aspx");
    }

    private void ConfigurePageLayout()
    {
        Master.ShowTopMenu = false;
        Master.ShowTitle = true;
        Master.ShowUserLogin = false;
        Master.PageTitle = "Login As Screen";
        Master.FormTitle = "Login As Screen";
    }

    private int AuthenticateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        // Authenticate user logic
        return DataService.Contact.SelectLogin(username, password);
    }

    private void InitiateUserSession(string username)
    {
        // Set session variables for the authenticated user
        Session["FromLogin"] = "Yes";
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, false);
    }

    private void RedirectAuthenticatedUser()
    {
        // Redirect the authenticated user to the appropriate page
        Response.Redirect("~/YourAuthenticatedPage.aspx");
    }

    private void DisplayAuthenticationError()
    {
        // Display an authentication error message
        cusValWrongLogin.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a high chance you would spend more time trying to get this to work than it would take to migrate to .Net 7. It can be surprisingly difficult just getting Azure AD to work in .Net Framework 4.8, and that's with lots of documentation. I've considered doing this for an ASPX project in the past and decided to upgrade instead, and am glad I did

Comment: Refer this [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74703197/19648279) which explains the Azure AD Authentication in a ASP.Net Framework Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Andrew Williamson for the comment.

If you don't want to migrate and still want to use the Legacy ASP.NET Framework, check the below steps.

With your Application Folder Structure and code, it is clear that, you are adding the code related to Azure AD Authentication manually.

We have few ways to Integrate the Azure AD code within our application automatically.

***Way 1 :***

Refer the [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74703197/19648279) which I have answered to get the sample code of Azure AD Integration.

***Way 2 :***

- While creating WebApp, select the Authentication type as Microsoft.
  [image]
- This step makes you to setup the automatic configuration of Azure AD registered app in your application.
- Select the correct tenant. As you have already registered the app in AD, select the same app.

[image]

- All the required packages will be Installed. And the required setting with values will be set in `Web.config` file.

***`Web.config` file:***

```cs
 <appSettings>
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="**********" />
    <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" />
    <add key="ida:Domain" value="****.onmicrosoft.com" />
    <add key="ida:TenantId" value="**********" />
    <add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44346/signin-oidc" />
  </appSettings>
```

- The default code uses the `OpenIdConnectAuthentication`.
- In `App_Start` folder, `StartupAuth.cs` file will be created with Code related to Authentication configuration.

[image]

***Way 3:***

- If you are sure about the code, you can configure it manually as explained in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project).

***Output:***
[image]