# Azure AD Authentication with legacy ASP.Net 4.5 Web Application in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have legacy ASP.Net 4.5 Web Application running with Windows Authentication build in Visual Studio 2015.
I am currently working to migrate Windows Authentication to Azure AD authentication.

Azure App (for this) is already setup within Azure portal.I am trying to configure it in Global.asax.cs. Below code apparently runs without any errors, but I am expecting it will open MS login page for user to login and redirect the token information back to application URL to use. which it is not doing. Any Idea? Any available option?

My hands are tied as Migration of application to latest framework is not an option. Application was built in Visual Studio 2015, currently using to update it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using Owin;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Owin.Builder;

namespace CCPOS_Staff_Interface123
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication, IOwinContext
    {
        private IAppBuilder _app;
        public new IAppBuilder App => _app;

        public IAuthenticationManager Authentication
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public IDictionary<string, object> Environment
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public TextWriter TraceOutput
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        IOwinRequest IOwinContext.Request
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        IOwinResponse IOwinContext.Response
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public T Get<T>(string key)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public IOwinContext Set<T>(string key, T value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            // Initialize OWIN
            _app = new AppBuilder();

            // Configure authentication using the IAppBuilder instance (_app)
            ConfigureAuth(_app);

        }

        private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure your authentication middleware (e.g., OpenID Connect, Cookie Authentication) here
            // Replace the following lines with your authentication configuration
            // app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication();
            // app.UseCookieAuthentication();


            // Configure authentication
            AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;

            var clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
            var authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"] + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
            var postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                RedirectUri = "http://localhost:56026/",
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    // Configure token validation parameters if needed
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry my .net C# skills are bit rusty. Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check this [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77079880/19648279) once.And try to configure same in your Framework.

Comment: @Harshitha tried that, but it is throwing this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77413198/error-idx21323-requirenonce-is-system-boolean-openidconnectprotocolvalidati

Comment: Will check from my end and let you know.

Comment: What is the Authentication type you are using ?

Comment: Are you able to login if you are using `https`? Are you getting the error locally or in the deployed app ?

Comment: I see that you have posted a new question with .Net Framework 4.7, Are you still looking sol for the existing question with .Net framework 4.5?

Comment: It would be great if Implementation can be done using .Net Framework 4.5.

Comment: Gave the configuration for [4.7 version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77445961/19648279).Will try to work for 4.5 and let you know. Mean while check and confirm the 4.7 version from your end.

Answer (score 1):

In order to migrate from Windows Authentication to Azure AD Authentication, I have disabled `Windows Authentication`, Disabled `Anonymous Authentication`.

[image]

- Initially I got the below error.

[image]

- Installed the below NuGet Packages

```cs
Microsoft.Owin
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect
```

[image]

As per your [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77413198/19648279), instead of `Startup.cs`, create a new file (StartupAuth.cs) under `App_Start` folder and write the code in it.

- After configuring everything with the required packages and code, I got the below error.

[image]

As mentioned in the [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63218408/19648279), the issue seems to be with the older 4.5 version.

I got the same error even in VS 2022 `ASP.NET 4.5` Version.

As suggested in the above SOLink I have tried with [4.7 version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77445961/19648279) and able to authenticate the app without any issues.