# How to integrate Azure AD Authentication in ASP.NET (on .NET 4.7) Web application using Owin without enablling Anonymouse Authentication in Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, authentication, owin

I have integrated the Azure Authentication using Owin in ASP.NET web application running on .NET 4.7 with Visual Studio 2015 (it's a legacy application).

To be able to connect to the Azure MS login page, I have to enable "Anonymous Authentication" in the project properties to make it work:

[image]

What are my options if I want disable to the Anonymous Authentication, after disable it does not work and throws the below error.

[image]

My `Startup.cs` file looks something like this

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Notifications;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Project1.Startup))]
namespace Project1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // The Client ID is used by the application to uniquely identify itself to Azure AD.
        string clientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];

        // RedirectUri is the URL where the user will be redirected to after they sign in.
        string redirectUri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"];

        // Tenant is the tenant ID (e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com, or 'common' for multi-tenant)
        static string tenant = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tenant"];

        // Authority is the URL for authority, composed by Microsoft identity platform endpoint and the tenant name (e.g. https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0)
        string authority = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"], tenant);

        /// <summary>
        /// Configure OWIN to use OpenIdConnect 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="app"></param>
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                // PostLogoutRedirectUri is the page that users will be redirected to after sign-out. In this case, it is using the home page
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                // ResponseType is set to request the code id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
                // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to OnAuthenticationFailed method
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                }
            }
        );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handle failed authentication requests by redirecting the user to the home page with an error in the query string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
        {
            context.HandleResponse();
            context.Response.Redirect("/?errormessage=" + context.Exception.Message);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
}
```

My `HomeController` looks something like this:

```
using Project1.Classes;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;

namespace Project1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                    new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
            return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index", "Admin");
        }

        public ActionResult Error()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

One option can be if I use the Javascript ADAL or MSAL library to get the token on the client side and pass it to the server-side application? which may be a little bit of work to change the current application structure.

What are the available options and implementation? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Initially even I got the same error when I disabled the `Windows Authentication` and `Anonymous Authentication`.

```cs
 HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized
 You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.
```

- I have done few changes in my `Web.config` and updated the NuGet Packages versions.

***Properties:***

[image]

Below NuGet Packages worked for me.

***My `Web.config`:***

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <location path="Account">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.6.0" newVersion="4.0.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.2" newVersion="4.0.1.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.1" newVersion="4.2.0.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Encodings.Web" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.5.1" newVersion="4.0.5.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.ValueTuple" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.2.0" newVersion="7.0.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.3.0" newVersion="7.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.3.0" newVersion="7.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.3.0" newVersion="7.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.3.0" newVersion="7.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.3.0" newVersion="7.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.2.0" newVersion="7.0.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.2.0" newVersion="4.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.2.0" newVersion="4.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <!--<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>-->

  <appSettings>
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="**********" />
    <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" />
    <add key="ida:Domain" value="**********.onmicrosoft.com" />
    <add key="ida:TenantId" value="**********" />
    <add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44338/signin-oidc" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

***My `StartupAuth.cs`:***

```cs
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.Owin.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using Owin;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
        private static string aadInstance = EnsureTrailingSlash(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"]);
        private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
        private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

        string authority = aadInstance + tenantId + "/v2.0";

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,

                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {
                        AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                        {
                            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
                        },

                        SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                        {
                            string name = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("preferred_username").Value;
                            context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name, string.Empty));
                            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    }
                });
       app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
        }

        private static string EnsureTrailingSlash(string value)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                value = string.Empty;
            }

            if (!value.EndsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                return value + "/";
            }

            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

***Output:***
[image]